# Extract Tar File inside Memory Filesystem

Tags: python, memory, tar, fs

I have trouble using memoryfs:
https://docs.pyfilesystem.org/en/latest/reference/memoryfs.html:

I'm trying to extract tar inside a memoryFS, but I cant use mem_fs because it is an object and cant get the real / memory path...

```
from fs import open_fs, copy
import fs
import tarfile

mem_fs = open_fs('mem://')

print(mem_fs.isempty('.'))

fs.copy.copy_file('//TEST_FS', 'test.tar', mem_fs, 'test.tar')

print(mem_fs.listdir('/'))

with mem_fs.open('test.tar') as tar_file:
    print(tar_file.read())
    tar = tarfile.open(tar_file) // I cant create the tar ...
    tar.extractall(mem_fs + 'Extract_Dir') // Cant extract it too...
```

Can someone help me, it is possible to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to `tarfile.open` is a filename. You're (a) passing it an open file object, and (b) even if you were to pass in a filename, `tarfile` doesn't know anything about your in-memory filesystem and so wouldn't be able to find the file.

Fortunately, `tarfile.open` has a `fileobj` argument that accepts an open file object, so you can write:

```
with mem_fs.open('test.tar', 'rb') as tar_file:
    tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=tar_file)
    t.list()
```

Note that you need to open the file in binary mode (`rb`).

Of course, now you have a second problem: while you can open and read the archive, the `tarfile` module *still* doesn't know about your in-memory filesystem, so attempting to extract files will simply extract them to your local filesystem, which is probably not what you want.

To extract into your in-memory filesystem, you're going to need to read the data from the tar archive member and write it yourself. Here's one option for doing that:

```
import fs
import os
import pathlib
import tarfile

mem_fs = fs.open_fs('mem://')
fs.copy.copy_file('/', '{}/example.tar.gz'.format(os.getcwd()),
                  mem_fs, 'example.tar.gz')

with mem_fs.open('example.tar.gz', 'rb') as fd:
    tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=fd)

    # iterate over list of members
    for member in tar.getmembers():

        # if the member is a file
        if member.isfile():

            # create any necessary directories
            p = pathlib.Path(member.path)
            mem_fs.makedirs(str(p.parent), recreate=True)

            # open the archive member
            with mem_fs.open(member.path, 'wb') as memfd, \
                    tar.extractfile(member.path) as tarfd:
                # and write the data into the memory fs
                memfd.write(tarfd.read())
```

The `tarfile.TarFile.extractfile` method returns an open file object to a tar archive member, rather than extracting the file to disk.

Note that the above isn't an optimal solution if you're working with large files (since it reads the entire archive member into memory before writing it out).

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is exactly what I needed.